# Plotting the logarithm of bin counts with Histogram3D

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, histograms

I am using `Histogram3D` to plot 2d data. Sometimes with `Histogram` I use double logarithmic axis to view e.g. power laws, using the option

```
Histogram[data, ScalingFunctions -> {"Log","Log"}]
```

But with Histogram3D, the `ScalingFunctions` only affects with bin widths. Is there a way to get each of the bin counts/heights (the vertical heights in the picture) to be logarithmic as well?

[image]

Comment: The documentation for [`ScalingFunctions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ScalingFunctions.html) clearly indicates that there can be more than two functions, i.e., "{Subscript[s, 1], Subscript[s, 2], ...}    use scaling function specification Subscript[s, i] for direction i"

Comment: I tried using thee "Logs" (as there are three axes) and it didn't scale the axes, it just caused to the plot to crash. Increasing the bin width size enough brought it back. So you can't vary the bin widths arbitrarily and simultaneously chose "Log" for the third scaling function.

Comment: They also should give examples of the syntax use. They seem to do that in many other cases, but in Histogram3D they should provide an example of using three logarithmic axes. Allowing people to submit examples would help.

Answer (score 5):

You can add a third scaling function to affect the vertical axis:

```
Histogram3D[RandomReal[{0, 1}, {1000, 2}],
   ScalingFunctions -> {"Linear", "Linear", "Log"}]
```

[image]